# how to make an Entry Array List?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have a sharedPreference class which contains strings. in each strings there is a decimal number. I want to bring them all to an **Entry** Array list in another activity. how can I do that?
Thanks.

Here is first the Sharedpreferences class:

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //about 30 Strings
        String w1 = prefs.getString("w1", "");
        String w2 = prefs.getString("w2", "");
        String w3 = prefs.getString("w3", "");
        String w4 = prefs.getString("w4", "");
        String w5 = prefs.getString("w5", "");
        String w6 = prefs.getString("w6", "");
```

here is a part of the second activity

```
private LineData generateLineData() {

    //Introduce the Array list which we made as entries
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();


    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "data series");
    set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setCircleSize(5f);
    set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
```

Here is the original source code:

```
package com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample;



public class CombinedChartActivity extends DemoBase {

private CombinedChart mChart;
private final int itemcount = 12;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_combined);

    mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);

    // draw bars behind lines
    mChart.setDrawOrder(new DrawOrder[] {
            DrawOrder.BAR, DrawOrder.BUBBLE, DrawOrder.CANDLE,     DrawOrder.LINE, DrawOrder.SCATTER
    });

    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);

    CombinedData data = new CombinedData(mMonths);

    data.setData(generateLineData());
    data.setData(generateBarData());
//        data.setData(generateBubbleData());
//         data.setData(generateScatterData());
//         data.setData(generateCandleData());

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
}

private LineData generateLineData() {

    LineData d = new LineData();

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(15, 10), index));

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setCircleSize(5f);
    set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));

    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    d.addDataSet(set);

    return d;
}

private BarData generateBarData() {

    BarData d = new BarData();

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
        entries.add(new BarEntry(getRandom(15, 30), index));

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "Bar DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    d.addDataSet(set);

    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    return d;
}

protected ScatterData generateScatterData() {

    ScatterData d = new ScatterData();

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(20, 15), index));

    ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(entries, "Scatter DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    set.setScatterShapeSize(7.5f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    d.addDataSet(set);

    return d;
}

protected CandleData generateCandleData() {

    CandleData d = new CandleData();

    ArrayList<CandleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<CandleEntry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
        entries.add(new CandleEntry(index, 20f, 10f, 13f, 17f));

    CandleDataSet set = new CandleDataSet(entries, "Candle DataSet");
    set.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
    set.setBodySpace(0.3f);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    d.addDataSet(set);

    return d;
}

protected BubbleData generateBubbleData() {

    BubbleData bd = new BubbleData();

    ArrayList<BubbleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BubbleEntry>();

    for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
        float rnd = getRandom(20, 30);
        entries.add(new BubbleEntry(index, rnd, rnd));
    }

    BubbleDataSet set = new BubbleDataSet(entries, "Bubble DataSet");
    set.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set.setHighlightCircleWidth(1.5f);
    set.setDrawValues(true);
    bd.addDataSet(set);

    return bd;
}

private float getRandom(float range, float startsfrom) {
    return (float) (Math.random() * range) + startsfrom;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.combined, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionToggleLineValues: {
            for (DataSet<?> set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
                if (set instanceof LineDataSet)
                    set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
            }

            mChart.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.actionToggleBarValues: {
            for (DataSet<?> set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
                if (set instanceof BarDataSet)
                    set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
            }

            mChart.invalidate();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Wharts the problem you are facing?

Comment: @user3676184 need to know how to make Entry array list from strings and how to bring it to the second activity and then employ it as "entries"!

Comment: Exactly what is an `Entry`?

Comment: What are the attributes of Entry?

Comment: What is Entry ? getter setter  Class ??

Comment: generateLineData() is a method which creates charts. It uses a library. there is no any attribute. Please check the original source code I added.

Comment: You still have not explained what an `Entry` is.  Until you do, nobody can help you.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, seems that Entry is an inner code coming from the library. I think if we can make an array list in "for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(20, 15), index));" then it is done.

Comment: Does `Entry` implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`?  Are you asking how to turn a `String` into an `Entry`, how to pass something from one `Activity` to another, or both?

Answer (score 0):

If your `sharedprefernce` keys are in w1,w2....w30 sequence, then

In activity #1

`ArrayList<String> list=new ArryList<String>();
        for(int i=1;i<=30;i++){
            list.add(prefs.getString("w"+i, ""));
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra("list_data",list);
        startActivity(intent);`

In activity #2

`ArrayList<String> entries = ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getExtras("list_data");
        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "data series");`

Comment: It doesn't accept entries as String or Double. it should be made by Entry as it is showed in the original source code.